# Check the filesystem format with BusyBox (stat -f and df -T do not work)

Tags: linux, filesystems, busybox, stat

I am using latest BusyBox v1.22.1 in my target. I want to check the filesystem type using `stat -f` or `df -T` but busybox doesn't support such commands. `busybox help` shows `stat` command as supported but while executing its showing as

```
stat: not found.
```

How can I check the filesystem type using BusyBox?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of components of BusyBox are optional. Depending on what compromise was made between size and functionality at compile time, utilities and options may or may not be available.

On Linux, you can get filesystem information from `/proc`. Run `df -P /some/file` to find the mount point for `/some/file`, then search that in `/proc/mounts` and extract the filesystem type. Assuming you have awk and have no whitespace in mount points, the following command prints the filesystem type that `/some/file` is on:

```
</proc/mounts awk -v mount_point="$(df -P /some/file | awk 'NR==2 {print $6}')" '$2 == mount_point {print $3}'
```

Comment: @user81906 you should mark this answer as accepted if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable `stat` and `du` on the `.config` before build:

```
CONFIG_DU=y
CONFIG_STAT=y
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, busybox commands may not always have the symlink to busybox, or may not be on your PATH. On RHEL6 "busybox stat -f /dev/XXXX" works.

Answer (score 0):

If `busybox help` shows `stat`, that would imply the applet is implemented. And if `stat` returns "not found", that may just be that a link for it to `busybox` was not created (and busybox has been configured to execute files when invoking applets).

Then since you're able to run `busybox help`, you should also be able to run `busybox stat` as an alternative to `stat`:

```
busybox stat -fc %T /
```